# Write a program that performs mathematical computation

Tags: python, math, decimal, computation

I'm taking my very first programming class ever and the second lab is already kicking my butt.

the prof wants us to write a program that will get measurement from the user in feet with a decimal (input) and then display that number in feet and inches separately (output).

I'm confused on how to get started. our result is suppose to look like "10.25 feet is equivalent to 10 feet 3 inches"

this is what i have so far:

```
print ("This program will convert your measurement (in feet) into feet and inches.")
print ()

# input section
userFeet = int(input("Enter feet: "))

# conversion
feet = ()
inches = feet * 12

#output section
print ("You are",userFeet, "tall.")
print (userFeet "feet is equivalent to" feet "feet" inches "inches")
```

and i don't know where to go from here. i understand converting feet into inches and vice versa. but i don't understand converting from feet to feet AND inches separately.

please help if you can! thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to mend your code with comments to what I have changed.

```
import math # This is a module. This allows you to access more commands. You can see the full list of "math" commands with this link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

print ("This program will convert your measurement (in feet) into feet and inches.")
print ()

# input section
userFeet = float(input("Enter feet: ")) # You used integer, which would not support decimal numbers. Float values can, and it is noted with float()

# conversion
feet = math.floor(userFeet) # This uses the floor command, which is fully explained in the link.
inches = (userFeet - feet) * 12

#output section
print ("You are", str(userFeet), "tall.")
print (userFeet, "feet is equivalent to", feet, "feet", inches, "inches") # You forgot to add the commas in the print command.
```

Answer (score 1):

The feet you will print is just the integer part of userFeet. The inches is the decimal one after the conversion. Much like 200 min is 3 hours and 20 mins ☺. So:

```
from math import floor
print ("This program will convert your measurement (in feet) into feet and inches.")
print ()

# input section
userFeet = float(input("Enter feet: "))

# conversion
feet = floor(userFeet) # this function simply returns the integer part of whatever is passed to it
inches = (userFeet - feet) * 12

#output section
print("You are {} tall.".format(userFeet))
print("{0} feet is equivalent to {1} feet {2:.3f} inches".format(userFeet, feet, inches))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple hints:

userFeet cannot be an integer (since it contains decimals).

The number of feet can be floored to integer from the float/double type.

The number of inches can be calculated by multiplying the difference of userFeet and feet (`userFeet - feet`) with 12 and rounding it to nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
10.25 feet => 10feet + 0.25 feet => 10feet and 0.25*12inch => 10feet 3inch
```

So take the decimal part and multiply by 12 to get it in inches then just show the number of feet and number of inches together.